# Как включить source-map для css в приложении create-react-app?

Tags: css, reactjs, отладка, webpack

Переношу шаблон в CRA. Стили ведут себя не вполне правильно. Devtools указывает на инлайн-стили, вставленные webpack-ом, ковыряться в которых очень неудобно.
Изначально стили в SCSS, собраны в один файл CSS с source-map и так уже импортированы в приложение.
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы devtools показывал, если не на исходный scss, то хотя бы на конкретные строки в импортируемом файле css?
Уточнения:

- без eject. Рассматриваю react-app-rewire, но пока не очень понимаю, как его конфигурировать.
- SCSS собран в CSS по документации CRA. Source-map включены.
- при билде приложения так же создаётся source-map файл конечного файла CSS. Но в браузере я вижу только инлайн-стили. Может, что-то в devtools нужно включить?

Answer (score 0):

Есть официальная документация create-react-app.

> https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/ - github.
>   Из документации можно понять, что все сложные конфигурации можно производить после eject-a всех конфигов с помощью команды `npm run eject`.

Так же есть инструкция для добавления своего препроцессора:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc

Вариант с экспортом конфигурации:

1. Выполнить команду `npm run eject`
2. Перейти в файл `webpack.config.dev.js` и добавить в css-loader свойство `sourceMaps: true` | https://monosnap.com/file/ad179NTDG6wSKbfNDt8V9zdjDpcfJC
   https://monosnap.com/file/EOKbI8K5FxBViROJZR0WDf31JA2j1H - Получаем sourceMaps для css.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Внёс поправки в вопрос.
scss собираю как раз по этой инструкции + опция мапа.
Eject не хотелось бы. Или это не страшно?
Мап-файл присутствует в финальной сборке, но не влияет на devtools.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю - необходимо добавить опцию в css-loader.
После этого source-maps будут подхватываться.
Как сделать это без eject-a - не могу подсказать.

Обычно любому проекту необходима гибкость и конфигурация для чего создается либо своя сборка, либо модифицируется template.

Исходя из этого - eject это неизбежно если сборка будет использоваться для разработки.

Comment: Возможно стоит подумать о своей сборке или взять уже готовую:
1) https://reactjs.org/community/starter-kits.html
2) https://michalzalecki.com/the-best-react-boilerplate/